# Laravel + predis + Redis cluster - MOVED / no connection to 127.0.0.1:6379

Tags: laravel, redis, azure-caching

I have a laravel (5.3) app with redis used for sessions (using predis). Everything works as long as I use a single redis node (using default approach from *config/database.php*). As soon as I switch to a Redis cluster though I am starting to get MOVED error like 50% of the time (based on googling I understand that this should be managed by predis, but somehow isn't).

I tried changing the cluster parameter to true, but then I get a weird error

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]
```

Although the redis cluster that I use is deployed in Azure (and is configured via .env file) and the parameters are accepted without any problem when a single node is used.

**Configuration**

Here is the laravel configuration that I have (as mentioned earlier, it's the standard default)

```
'redis' => [

        'client' => 'predis',
        'cluster' => false,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

    ],
```

For Redis, I use Azure Redis Cache Cluster Premium P1, 2 shards (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-how-to-premium-clustering)).

**UPDATE 2**

So far I also tried the following variations of the config:

1. Setting cluster to true
2. Setting cluster to redis
3. Adding default -> cluster set to redis
4. Adding default -> options set to array('cluster', 'redis')

All the time I am getting MOVED error...

My Redis version is 3.2, predis/predis package 1.1.1

**Working config for predis 1.1+**

```
'redis' => [
        'cluster' => true,

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ] ,
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis',
             'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
        ],
    ],
```

Big thank you for all the help :)

Comment: Can we see your configuration? This is handled automagically by Laravel through Predis. When invoking the Predis\Client, an argument is passed, such as `['client' => 'redis']`. This automagically handles the `-ASK` and `-MOVED` responses.

Comment: I've added the confguration.

Comment: It looks like the options are supposed to be outside of the `default` key, and the array should be `key=>value` (where you have it as two values). So, I'd say try: `'redis' => [ 'cluster' => true, 'default' => [ /*your config*/ ], 'options' => [ 'cluster' => 'redis' ], ]`. Let us know.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Note

The information and config specified here is for Laravel 5.3 and below. The redis config structure was changed in Laravel 5.4+.

#### TL;DR

- `'cluster' => true` should be true to create one aggregate client that handles multiple nodes.
- `'options' => ['cluster' => 'redis']` needs to be added to the configuration as a sibling of `default` (not a child) in order to tell Predis to handle the server-side clustering provided by Azure.
- if using auth with server-side clustering, `'options' => [ 'cluster' => 'redis', 'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)], ]` will be needed to auth newly discovered cluster nodes.

#### Full Text

In the redis configuration, you can set up multiple connections to multiple redis instances. The `cluster` option tells Laravel how to handle those multiple defined connections.

If `cluster` is set to `false`, Laravel will create individual `\Predis\Client` instances for each connection. Each connection can be accessed individually, and will not have any relation to another connection.

If `cluster` is set to `true`, Laravel will create an aggregate `\Predis\Client` instance using all the defined connections. With no other configuration, this is kind of a "fake" cluster. It uses client-side sharding to distribute the keyspace and may require external monitoring and maintenance to ensure a proper key load balance.

The issue you're running into, however, is that Azure implements (presumably) a real server-side Redis cluster, which handles automatic sharding of the keyspace. In this instance, the nodes know about each other and talk to each other, and may go up and down. This is where `MOVED` and `ASK` responses come from.

The `Predis` library can automatically handle these responses, but only when you tell it that it needs to. In this case, you need to tell the `Predis` client that it needs to handle clustering, and this is done by Laravel through the `options` array on the `redis` configuration.

On the `redis` configuration, the `options` key should be a sibling of your connections (i.e. `default`), not a child. Additionally, the options should be specified as `key => value` pairs.

So, your configuration should look like:

```
'redis' => [
    'cluster' => true,

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
    ],
],
```

The `cluster` key under the `redis` config will tell Laravel to create an aggregate `Predis\Client` instance that may handle multiple nodes, and the `cluster` key under the `options` array will tell that instance that it needs to handle server-side clustering, not client-side clustering.

#### Auth

The original connection parameters (including authentication) are not shared with connections to new nodes discovered via `-MOVED` and `-ASK` responses. So, any errors you previously got from `-MOVED` responses will now just convert to `NOAUTH` errors. However, the server-side `'cluster'` configuration allows for a `'parameters'` sibling which defines a list of parameters to use with newly discovered nodes. This is where you can put your auth parameters to use with new nodes.

I believe this will look something like:

```
'redis' => [
    'cluster' => true,

    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
        'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
    ],
],
```

---

Fair warning, this is all information I just got from research and code diving. While I have used Redis with Laravel, I have not used server side clustering (yet), so this still may not work.

Some useful pieces of information I came across while looking into this:

Predis issue discussing connecting to a redis-cluster:
https://github.com/nrk/predis/issues/259#issuecomment-117339028

> It looks like you did not configure Predis to use redis-cluster but instead you are using it with the plain old client-side sharding logic (which is also the default behaviour). You should configure the client setting the option cluster with the value redis to let the client know it must play along with redis-cluster. Quick example:
>
> `$client = new Predis\Client([$node1, $node2, ...], ['cluster' => 'redis']);`
>
> Doing so will make it possible for the client to automatically handle -MOVED or -ASK responses coming from Redis nodes.

MS article discussing clustering on redis cache:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/redis-cache/cache-how-to-premium-clustering#how-do-i-connect-to-my-cache-when-clustering-is-enabled

> You can connect to your cache using the same endpoints, ports, and keys that you use when connecting to a cache that does not have clustering enabled. Redis manages the clustering on the backend so you don't have to manage it from your client.

Laravel code for creating `Predis\Client` instances:
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/v5.3.28/src/Illuminate/Redis/Database.php#L25-L66

Comment: Thank you, at least now I see different error messages :) It starts with "No connection available in the pool", which then turns into "ServerException in Client.php line 370: NOAUTH Authentication required." happening like 50% of the time. It looks like although predis handled the MOVED message, it doesn't do authentication on the new node. Any suggestions how to make this work? :)

Comment: @LechMigdal I have updated my answer to include a suggestion for handling authentication.

Comment: Thank you :) And any suggestions for predis 1.1.1? I see that setDefaltParameters is no longer there (was there in 1.0.3 from what I see).

Comment: OK, I found the missing small piece, instead of setting custom function, since 1.1.0 you can do the following:   'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis',
             'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
        ], Big thanks for your help!

Comment: @LechMigdal Awesome. Thanks for the update. I have updated my answer to reflect the new information. Glad you got it working!

Comment: @patricus I am using the same configuration, but I am still getting the same error. I am using laravel 5.3 and trying to use AWS ElasticCache Redis cluster Mode enabled setup

Comment: hey @patricus your post was very useful, but i'm stuck at the part where I have to specify multiple clusters.. please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56497809/how-to-make-laravel-work-with-redis-cluster-on-aws)

Answer (score 3):

Related: [Laravel + Redis Cache via SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762751/laravel-redis-cache-via-ssl/48876398#48876398)

To which I've answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48876398/663058

**Relevant details below:**

If you have clustering *and* TLS then you'll need a the following config (tested with AWS Elasticache):

```
'redis' => [
        'client' => 'predis',
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

        // Note! for single redis nodes, the default is defined here.
        // keeping it here for clusters will actually prevent the cluster config
        // from being used, it'll assume single node only.
        //'default' => [
        //    ...
        //],

        // #pro-tip, you can use the Cluster config even for single instances!
        'clusters' => [
            'default' => [
                [
                    'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
                    'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                    'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
                ],
            ],
            'options' => [ // Clustering specific options
                'cluster' => 'redis', // This tells Redis Client lib to follow redirects (from cluster)
            ]
        ],
        'options' => [
            'parameters' => [ // Parameters provide defaults for the Connection Factory
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null), // Redirects need PW for the other nodes
                'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),  // Redirects also must match scheme
            ],
            'ssl'    => ['verify_peer' => false], // Since we dont have TLS cert to verify
        ]
    ]
```

Explaining the above:

- `'client' => 'predis'`: This specifies the PHP Library Redis driver to use (predis).
- `'cluster' => 'redis'`: This tells Predis to assume server-side clustering. Which just means "follow redirects" (e.g. `-MOVED` responses). When running with a cluster, a node will respond with a `-MOVED` to the node that you must ask for a specific key.

  - If you don't have this enabled with Redis Clusters, Laravel will throw a `-MOVED` exception 1/*n* times, *n* being the number of nodes in Redis cluster (it'll get lucky and ask the right node every once in awhile)
- `'clusters' => [...]`: Specifies a list of nodes, but setting just a 'default' and pointing it to the [AWS 'Configuration endpoint'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Endpoints.html#Endpoints.Find.RedisCluster) will let it find any/all other nodes dynamically (recommended for Elasticache, because you don't know when nodes are comin' or goin').
- `'options'`: For Laravel, can be specified at the top-level, cluster-level, and node option. (they get combined in Illuminate before being passed off to Predis)
- `'parameters'`: These 'override' the default connection settings/assumptions that Predis uses for new connections. Since we set them explicitly for the 'default' connection, these aren't used. But for a cluster setup, they are critical. A 'master' node may send back a redirect (`-MOVED`) and unless the parameters are set for `password` and `scheme` it'll assume defaults, and that new connection to the new node will fail.

Answer (score 2):

For AWS elasticcache redis cluster the above configuration did not work, however below are working for me. Also mentioned in the documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/redis#configuration

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => 'predis',
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
    ],
    'clusters' => [
        'default' => [
            [
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 2):

After applying a lot of suggestions at last I found the solution by using phpredis instead of Redis. Use the below code:

```
    'redis' => [

    'client' => 'phpredis',
    'clusters' => [
        'default' => [
            [
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    ]

],
```

use official doc for better understanding [Laravel Redis with clusters](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/redis#clusters)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [ https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/redis ].

Make sure you have the proper library

```
composer require predis/predis
```

In config/database.php as well as config/queue.php [ if your queue is also using clustered reddis]

```
'redis' => [

    'client' => 'predis',
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
    ],
    'clusters' => [
        'default' => [
            [
                'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                'database' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    ],

]
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => 'predis',
    'cluster' => true,
    'options' => [
        'cluster' => 'redis',
        'parameters' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
            ],
        ],
    'clusters' => [
         'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_DEFAULT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'jobs' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_JOBS_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_JOBS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'content' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_CONTENT_HOST', '127.0.01'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_CONTENT_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis'
        ],
    ]
]
```

to see how I got there, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56510512/766570)

Comment: I know this answer is years ago, but do you know how to configure each of cluster (default, jobs, etc) with different database (like default use 0, jobs use 1)?

Answer (score 0):

This result comes up in Google for predis+redis-cluster (no laravel). I and my team were struggling for hours with this issue, so I am putting this answer here for those who find this page getting that error while trying to connect to the Redis cluster directly:

```
$redis = new Predis\Client(
   ['tcp://127.0.0.1:6379'],
   ['cluster' => 'redis']
);
```