# Laravel + Redis Cache via SSL?

Tags: php, laravel, predis

I am trying to connect to Redis with predis 1.1 and SSL, using information https://github.com/nrk/predis, where in the example the following configuration is used:

```
// Named array of connection parameters:
$client = new Predis\Client([
  'scheme' => 'tls',
  'ssl'    => ['cafile' => 'private.pem', 'verify_peer' => true],
]);
```

My Laravel configuration looks like below:

```
'redis' => [
        'client' => 'predis',
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],

        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'redis',
            'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
            'scheme' => 'tls',
        ],
    ],
```

Unfortunately I am getting the following error:

```
ConnectionException in AbstractConnection.php line 155:
Error while reading line from the server. [tcp://MY_REDIS_SERVER_URL:6380]
```

Suggestions are appreciated :)

Comment: Please post your .env file. The error is where it says MY_REDIS_SERVER_URL in your .env

Comment: MY_REDIS_SERVER_URL is simply URL of the Redis server. I can reach it through the port 6379, but not via 6380. Both should be accessible (this is Azure Redis Cache, with 6380 opened by default).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, any suggestions? :)

Comment: Same here, I just can't make it work with SSL

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I was able to get it to work!

You need to move 'scheme' from `'options'` to `'default'`:

My working config:

```
'redis' => [
    'client' => 'predis',
    'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

    'default' => [
        'scheme' => 'tls',
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
    ],

    'options' => [
        'parameters' => ['password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null)],
    ],
],
```

Note: I had also removed the `'cluster'` option from `'options'`, but I don't suspect this to be the make-or-break with this problem.

In my final-final config, I changed it to: `'scheme' => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),` and then defined `REDIS_SCHEME=tls` in my env file instead.

Tested with AWS ElastiCache with TLS enabled.

**Edit:**
The above config only works with single-node redis. If you happen to enable clustering *and* TLS then you'll need a different config entirely.

```
'redis' => [
        'client' => 'predis',
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

        // Note! for single redis nodes, the default is defined here.
        // keeping it here for clusters will actually prevent the cluster config
        // from being used, it'll assume single node only.
        //'default' => [
        //    ...
        //],

        // #pro-tip, you can use the Cluster config even for single instances!
        'clusters' => [
            'default' => [
                [
                    'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
                    'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                    'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
                ],
            ],
            'options' => [ // Clustering specific options
                'cluster' => 'redis', // This tells Redis Client lib to follow redirects (from cluster)
            ]
        ],
        'options' => [
            'parameters' => [ // Parameters provide defaults for the Connection Factory
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null), // Redirects need PW for the other nodes
                'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),  // Redirects also must match scheme
            ],
        ]
    ]
```

Explaining the above:

- `'client' => 'predis'`: This specifies the PHP Library Redis driver to use (predis).
- `'cluster' => 'redis'`: This tells Predis to assume server-side clustering. Which just means "follow redirects" (e.g. `-MOVED` responses). When running with a cluster, a node will respond with a `-MOVED` to the node that you must ask for a specific key.
- If you don't have this enabled with Redis Clusters, Laravel will throw a `-MOVED` exception 1/*n* times, *n* being the number of nodes in Redis cluster (it'll get lucky and ask the right node every once in awhile)
- `'clusters' => [...]` : Specifies a list of nodes, but setting just a 'default' and pointing it to the [AWS 'Configuration endpoint'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Endpoints.html#Endpoints.Find.RedisCluster) will let it find any/all other nodes dynamically (recommended for Elasticache, because you don't know when nodes are comin' or goin').
- `'options'`: For Laravel, can be specified at the top-level, cluster-level, and node option. (they get combined in Illuminate before being passed off to Predis)
- `'parameters'`: These 'override' the default connection settings/assumptions that Predis uses for new connections. Since we set them explicitly for the 'default' connection, these aren't used. But for a cluster setup, they are critical. A 'master' node may send back a redirect (`-MOVED`) and unless the parameters are set for `password` and `scheme` it'll assume defaults, and that new connection to the new node will fail.

Comment: Excellent breakdown!

Somebody correct me if I'm wrong but after looking through the Laravel 5.5 source code, the top level `'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),` does nothing. To use clustering, you just have to have a top-level `clusters` array and, like @CenterOrbit mentions, **remove the top-level `default`** connection config. If Laravel finds a top-level key with the name of your connection (`default` by default), it won't look for the connection in the `clusters` config.

https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Redis/RedisManager.php#L72

Comment: Also per-cluster `options` that @CenterOrbit mentions requires you to unintuitively mix in an associative `options` value into your non-associative array of nodes, e.g.:

`'redis' => [ 'clusters' => [ 'default' => [ 'options' => [ 'cluster' => 'redis' ], [ 'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'), /* ... */ ], ], ], ]`

Comment: [A gist](https://gist.github.com/bericp1/f6f5ec3a59062ab2d6f2abbebb0a3b2c) with better formatting and more info related to [my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762751/laravel-redis-cache-via-ssl/48876398#comment91083956_48876398).

Answer (score 4):

Thank you [CenterOrbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/663058/centerorbit)!!

I can confirm the first solution does allow Laravel to connect to a Redis **server** over TLS. Tested with Redis 3.2.6 on AWS ElastiCache with TLS, configured as single node and single shard.

I can also confirm the second solution does allow Laravel to connect to a Redis **Cluster** over TLS. Tested with Redis 3.2.6 on AWS ElastiCache with TLS, configured with "Cluster Mode Enabled", 1 shard, 1 replica per shard.

I was receiving the following error when I first tried to implement the cluster solution:

```
Error: Unsupported operand types
```

I missed the additional set of array brackets when I moved the "default" settings into the "clusters" array.

**INCORRECT**

```
'clusters' => [
  'default' => [
    'scheme' ...
  ]
]
```

**CORRECT**

```
'clusters' => [
  'default' => [
    [
      'scheme' ...
    ]
  ]
]
```

I hope this saves someone else a bit of troubleshooting time.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted solution by CenterOrbit worked for me, as I was using AWS I had to add tls:// in my .env
Laravel

Answer (score 0):

tls://username:password@URL:PORT?database=0
Try it. It will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).