# AWS ElastiCache Redis can't connect from Laravel nad from redis-cli

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis

I'm having a problem connecting to ElastiCache Redis from Laravel application installed on EC2 instance or even using redis-cli from EC2 instance.

**Laravel**

I tried to use predis with configurations in database.php like

```
    'redis' => [
    'client' => 'predis',
    'default' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
        'database' => 0,
        'read_write_timeout' => -1,
        'timeout' => 0
    ],
],
```

and got '`Error while reading line from the server. [tcp:server here]`'

I tried with phpRedis extension with same configurations only change `'client' => 'phpredis'` and got error `read error on connection {"exception":"[object] (RedisException(code: 0): read error on connection at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Redis/Connectors/PhpRedisConnector.php:69)`

**Redis cli**

Using redis cli `redis-cli -h host_here -p 6379 -a password_here` I see prompt like `host:6379>` but typing any command throws error `Error: Connection reset by peer`

**ElastiCache Redis configurations**

[image]

My EC2 and elastic cache are in the same VPC and using telnet I can connect to redis instance

```
~$ telnet host 6379
Trying 172.31.23.113...
Connected to host.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: hm, when I created new redis instance without AUTH it started working. But issue is still there, why redis won't work with AUTH

Comment: Can you check this doc once -https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/auth.html ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Related: [Laravel + Redis Cache via SSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41762751/laravel-redis-cache-via-ssl/48876398#48876398)

To which I've answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48876398/663058

**Relevant details below:**

Since you have clustering *and* TLS then you'll need a different config entirely:

```
'redis' => [
        'client' => 'predis',
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', false),

        // Note! for single redis nodes, the default is defined here.
        // keeping it here for clusters will actually prevent the cluster config
        // from being used, it'll assume single node only.
        //'default' => [
        //    ...
        //],

        // #pro-tip, you can use the Cluster config even for single instances!
        'clusters' => [
            'default' => [
                [
                    'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),
                    'host'     => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
                    'port'     => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
                    'database' => env('REDIS_DATABASE', 0),
                ],
            ],
            'options' => [ // Clustering specific options
                'cluster' => 'redis', // This tells Redis Client lib to follow redirects (from cluster)
            ]
        ],
        'options' => [
            'parameters' => [ // Parameters provide defaults for the Connection Factory
                'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null), // Redirects need PW for the other nodes
                'scheme'   => env('REDIS_SCHEME', 'tcp'),  // Redirects also must match scheme
            ],
            'ssl'    => ['verify_peer' => false], // Since we dont have TLS cert to verify
        ]
    ]
```

Explaining the above:

- `'client' => 'predis'`: This specifies the PHP Library Redis driver to use (predis).
- `'cluster' => 'redis'`: This tells Predis to assume server-side clustering. Which just means "follow redirects" (e.g. `-MOVED` responses). When running with a cluster, a node will respond with a `-MOVED` to the node that you must ask for a specific key.

  - If you don't have this enabled with Redis Clusters, Laravel will throw a `-MOVED` exception 1/*n* times, *n* being the number of nodes in Redis cluster (it'll get lucky and ask the right node every once in awhile)
- `'clusters' => [...]`: Specifies a list of nodes, but setting just a 'default' and pointing it to the [AWS 'Configuration endpoint'](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Endpoints.html#Endpoints.Find.RedisCluster) will let it find any/all other nodes dynamically (recommended for Elasticache, because you don't know when nodes are comin' or goin').
- `'options'`: For Laravel, can be specified at the top-level, cluster-level, and node option. (they get combined in Illuminate before being passed off to Predis)
- `'parameters'`: These 'override' the default connection settings/assumptions that Predis uses for new connections. Since we set them explicitly for the 'default' connection, these aren't used. But for a cluster setup, they are critical. A 'master' node may send back a redirect (`-MOVED`) and unless the parameters are set for `password` and `scheme` it'll assume defaults, and that new connection to the new node will fail.

Answer (score 10):

I know this is pretty old but I was having the same issue myself. If anyone encounters this issue then see the solution [here](https://serverfault.com/a/891877) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/287c659d-98f0-4e86-bf4c-b5433603d5c2/how-to-connect-azureredis-from-rediscli?forum=azurecache).

It seems that when you enable `Encryption in-transit` in AWS Elasticache it prevents you from using redis-cli as it doesn't support TLS connections. Switching to another client should work. This [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/896423) has a list of TLS enabled clients.

**Edit:**

Did some more digging and found that using `stunnel` you can wrap your connection of redis-cli with ssl. [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/aws/comments/7p04p4/elasticache_encryption_in_transit/dtgferx/) is a guide for doing it.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using predis as client.

Then you can change Redis connection in config/database.php

```
'redis' => [
        'client' => 'predis',
        'default' => [
            'scheme' => 'tls',
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
```

You can add 'scheme' in that.

I am using Laravel 5.8 And then everything works great within Laravel.

But yes, as Redis doesn't provide TLS connection so redis-cli will still not work.